# Combobox selected index is wrong

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a method that calls and load my combobox. Once the call is made, i then added "All" to be first on the combobox. Unfortunately when this is added to the list, "All" takes the index of 0 which messes everything up. The selectedindex should be "a" as from the table. Is there a way to set "All" to be -1 as the index? What might be the best way to still have "a" as an index of 0 instead of an index of 1?

```
private void Load()
{
    List<string> all = dataSource.GetAll();

    if (all.Count > 1)
    {
        cbAll.Items.Clear();
        cbAll.BeginUpdate();


            cbAll.Items.Add("All");

            foreach (var item in all)
            {
                cbAll.Items.Add(item);
            }
            cbAll.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

table ITEM result

```
0 -- a
1 -- b
2 -- c
3 -- d
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't rely on the selected index, bind the ItemsSource to an `ObservableCollection<T>` and bind the SelectedItem to a property of type `T` and use the bound property to read the selection.

If you need the display value to differ from the selected value then wrap them in a small class:

```
public class Item
{
  public int Code { get; set; }
  public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

Then your ItemsSource is bound to a property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

public int Selection { get; set; }
```

Your DisplayMemberPath will be **Display**

Your SelectedValuePath will be **Code**

And your Xaml for the CombobBox will look like:

```
<ComboBox 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Display" 
          SelectedValuePath="Code" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Selection}"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

The index of the items in a combobox is zero based, so there is no way you can add an item at "-1". A selected index of "-1" means that you don't have any item selected.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx

> Gets or sets the index of the first item in the current selection or returns negative one (-1) if the selection is empty.
>
> ...
>
> Setting SelectedIndex in a Selector that supports multiple selections clears existing selected items and sets the selection to the item specified by the index. SelectedIndex returns -1 if selection is empty.
>
> If you set SelectedIndex to a value less that -1, an ArgumentException is thrown. If you set SelectedIndex to a value equal or greater than the number of child elements, the value is ignored.